# Gstreamer, C#, Appsink not getting samples from the pipeline

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

I am trying to play stream from my IP Camera, I used the OverlayWindow Handle with video sink it woks fine, but later I wanted to use appSink to capture samples and render frames my own, I am not getting the event OnNewSample fired. any help appreciated.
Here is the wiring pipeline with videosink,

```
_playbin = Gst.Parse.Launch("rtspsrc  name=src  !  application/x-rtp, media=video ! decodebin name=dbin  " +
    "! video/x-raw ! capsfilter name=caps ! videoconvert name=cnvt !  autovideosink  name=sink sync=false");
```

Here is my sample code,

```
Gst.Application.Init();
GtkSharp.GstreamerSharp.ObjectManager.Initialize();

var pipeline = new Pipeline("mypipeline");

// Create elements
var source = ElementFactory.Make("rtspsrc", "source");
var capsFilter = ElementFactory.Make("capsfilter", "caps");
var decode = ElementFactory.Make("decodebin", "decode");
var videoConvert = ElementFactory.Make("videoconvert", "convert");
var appSink = ElementFactory.Make("appsink", "sink") as AppSink;

// Set camera stream URI
source.SetProperty("uri", new GLib.Value("rtsp://stream-uri"));

// Configure app sink to receive video samples
appSink.SetProperty("emit-signals", new GLib.Value(true));
appSink.SetProperty("sync", new GLib.Value(false));
appSink["max-buffers"] = 1;

// Add elements to pipeline
pipeline.Add(source, decode, capsFilter, videoConvert, appSink);

// Link elements
source.Link(decode);
decode.Link(capsFilter);
capsFilter.Link(videoConvert);
videoConvert.Link(appSink);
appSink.Drop = false;
            
appSink.NewSample += (object o, NewSampleArgs args) => 
{
    ;
};

pipeline.SetState(State.Playing);
```